# getting product id's as invalid during implementation of In-app-purchase

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have created an e-book reader application.

I have added the application through itunes connect.

The app status is - Prepare for upload.

I have added 2 products to this application.

The status of products is - Ready for review.

In order to test In-app-purchase, I have

-created a development provisioning profile, with the same bundle id that i used while creating a new application through itunes connect.

-created a test user account through itunes connect.

I'm transferring the application to my device using this provisioning profile(Debug mode).

When i request for the products from my application i'm getting all the products as invalid.

I'm unable to figure out the root cause for this problem.

I've been scratching me head to solve this problem for a while now.

Any........Any help in this regard would be considered very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this problem by completing the Contracts, TAX & Banking section in Itunes Connect.
IOS PAID Applications contract shall be in affect to test In-App-Purchase in Sandbox environment.